# FrameworkElementFactory is Not Available in My VS2012

Tags: frameworkelementfactory

I tried to use FrameworkElementFactory for creating Templates. But it doesn't 
Show anything like that. It shows an error.

Someone in this forum told that its deprecated. then, how could i do that Template Creation without use of FrameworkElementFactory ??